# Ecommerce module causing to not to display of all the modules in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I'm new to drupal and e-commerce, I had followed steps given in [here.](http://drupalwatchdog.com/volume-1/issue-1/building-drupal-commerce-product-display)

once I'm deploying ecommerce module in location `sites\all\modules\custom`
it surprisingly does not shows any module in control panel of drupal administration.
I don't know what wrong I'm doing, some buddy suggested that need to put PHP safe mode should be off in **.htaccess** file, which will help to read **".info"** and **".module"** file read.

```
php_flag safe_mode Off
```

I'm using

```
1. drupal-7.31
2. ecommerce-7.x-4.x-dev
3. entity-7.x-1.x-dev 
4. rules-7.x-2.x-dev
5. token-7.x-1.x-dev 
6. views-7.x-3.x-dev 
7. addressfield-7.x-1.x-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't put contrib modules in sites/all/modules/custom, convention is to put them in sites/all/modules/contrib. But that's not likely to be the issue. More importantly , do not use the "ecommerce" project. The article you referenced is for the Drupal Commerce project, hosted at http://drupal.org/project/commerce